# How to get the values inside of a datatype variable?

Tags: sml, ml

Let's say I have the following tree datatype:

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;
val x = Node(10, Node(20, Empty, Empty), Node(30, Empty, Empty));
```

Here, x is a variable of type int tree. What I want to know is how can I dissect and evaluate the different parts of the tree given **only** the variable x?

For example in this function:

```
fun add(tree) = ....
add(x);
```

Say the function adds all of the values in the nodes of the tree, how would I exactly grab those values? I know for tuples you can just do:

```
#i(x, y, z, ......)
```

To grab the element at the i'th index. How would this type of functionality work with recursive datatypes?

Answer (score 1):

To get the values from a recursive datatype, you can just write a recursive function for it.

```
fun getValues(Node(v,l,r) : 'a tree) : 'a list = getValues(l) @ [v] @ getValues(r)
  | getValues(Empty) = []
```